# Python scipy.minimize

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a question about python scipy.minimize, I know if

```
x0 = np.array([0.5, 0])
```

then I can set the bound like this

```
bnds = ((0, None), (0, None))
```

but if my x0 has 1000 terms, and I want each of them to be in range (0,5), how should I set my bound?

Comment: Are you trying to say, each element for NumPy array x0 should lie in the range of 0 to 5 with over 1000 elements?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of [`scipy.optimize.Bounds`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html):

```py
scipy.optimize.minimize(..., bounds=Bounds(0, 5))
```